# Nothing happens when trying to download a Steam demo

Tags: steam

Sometimes, when I try to install a newly-released game demo on Steam, clicking the "Download Demo" button in the store page, from the built-in Steam browser, just does nothing - the only thing which is happening is the the mouse cursor momentarily changes from a link pointer to a regular arrow.

If I go to the store page from outside Steam and click the "download demo" button, it correctly prompts me to open Steam - but then it does nothing as well.

This has happened for me more than once, with more than one demo; but other demos download, install and run just fine. Can anyone provide a solution?

OS is Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Have you tried copy pasting the link url (e.g., `steam://install/99870/`) and running it from Win-R?

Comment: @failbadp tried it now, doesn't do anything (except for focusing on the Steam window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened also to me more than one time, with just released demo. Usually I wait the next day and it works.

I imagine that the problem could be caused by the fact that demo files are not yet globally distributed through all Steam server network.

I never tried, I will do next time, but maybe changing the download region from Steam -> Settings -> Download and Cloud could help.

Comment: I've tried changing the region to various other places, it didn't work. I'll wait until tomorrow and see if it can be downloaded.

Comment: Which demo are you trying to download, if i can ask?

Comment: doesn't really matter - as you wrote yourself it also happened to me with other demos, but yes, it only happened with newly-released one.

Comment: @Oak I suspect that the game, in the most recent case, was Anomaly: Warzone Earth. I had problems too to download it during the initial days, but now it seems working. Do you have news?

Comment: it is indeed the game, but that was a special case, as there was a global problem with the demo - as admitted by the game studios. However, regarding other demos, I still think your answer is accurate - so I'm accepting it; this demo was an exception, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue with Steam on Linux. Opening the Store page in a browser, clicking “Download Demo” there, and allowing xdg-open to open it with Steam, did trigger a download popup for me.